# ERROR：the function/feature is not implemented(the algorithm is patented....)

Tags: opencv-contrib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg8ml.png)

I already use CMake to compile the opencv-contrib,

and the xfeatures2d file is existd, it also has nonfree.hpp,but still post this error!

what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want to use sift and surf,and it perplex me a lot.

Comment: finally,I solve it.I used a raw computer that does'nt involve to opencv,and i start cmake,it make it.the error is gone!